# Gmail failing to catch spam from ml top-level domain - can I block all .ml addresses and send to spam?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, spam-prevention, domain

Gmail is failing to catch many spam messages a day from addresses like "raw4gftvdg_sgthesry@dewasoqeyodruna.ml" All are .ml addresses and have the same sender "name". I've reported them as spam but they keep bypassing the spam "filtering" that Google does.

Is there a way to set a filter to send all .ml address email to spam? I have no-one who emails me from Mali and it's obviously spammers.

Answer (score 1):

You can not filter by TLD in HTML Gmail.

However, while you are  asking to filter by TLD, you indicate that "all... ...have the same sender name."  If that is indeed the case, you can filter based on the sender name.

---

### Create a Filter using the sender name

---

Per Gmail: [Create rules to filter your emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccreate-a-filter)

1. Open [Gmail](https://mail.google.com).
2. In the search box at the top, click Show search options [image: image_1].
3. Enter your search criteria.
   *If you want to check that your search works correctly, test it by clicking **Search**.*
4. At the bottom of the search window, click **Create filter**
5. Choose what you’d like the filter to do.
6. Click **Create filter**.

[image: Create filter]

Comment: Doesn’t answer the question

Comment: It does answer the question Roman.  The answer is **No** (*"You cannot filter by TLD in HTML Gmail"*)

Comment: @BlindSpots Thank you for your time you have spent enriching this answer with a screencast. It adds great value to it, but on the other hand it exploits your private message titles and Inbox content to the public (you can run this GIF in any player, browser or viewer that allows it to be stopped at first frame or you can convert it to any non-animated format and the first frames becomes very readable). For your own privacy and security reasons I'd consider reuploading this screen cast with a background blurred .

Comment: @trejder I really appreciate the sound warning!  In this case, the image is from the [linked support page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccreate-a-filter "Gmail Help: Create a Filter").   I have updated the image in question to link back to the source support page in hopes of avoiding a similar concern in the future.